# Android - Starting an Intent After the First PhoneCall

Tags: java, android, android-intent, telephonymanager

I'm developing an application which needs to start an intent after the first phone call - but not after every phone call.

The following source should start an intent after a call - but how can it be modified to only do it once (after the first call is made) instead of after every call?

SOURCE:

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Toast.makeText( context, "incoming call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            IntentService = new Intent(context, PlayService.class).setAction("incoming_call");
            IntentService.putExtra("phone_number",intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) );
            if (SmsReceiver.bool)
            context.startService(IntentService);
            break;
```

or perhaps I could use:

```
EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to keep track of the number of calls made.

Comment: I'm very new to this. Might it be possible for you to show me an example of how I might be able to implement such a preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store a Boolean flag in persistent storage (e.g. SharedPreferences, file or database) to indicate if a call has been detected already. Initialise the flag to `false` and wrap your code in an `if` statement to check if the flag is `false`. Then, within the `if` statement, set the flag to `true` and your code won't enter the `if` statement in future.